# batch script to send email

Tags: email, batch-file, windows-server-2008

How to write a Windows batch script to send a mail? Give an example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use a third party tool such as blat (http://www.blat.net/).  Then in your batch file, you would have a line like the following:

blat -to foo@bar.com -f bar@foo.com -subject "Email Subject" -body "Email body" -server mysmtphost

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the installed SMTP Server of Windows.
And then run a power shell script:

```
$subject = $args[0]

# Create from/to addresses
$from = New-Object system.net.mail.MailAddress "remy@supertext.ch"
$to = New-Object system.net.mail.MailAddress "remy.blaettler@gmail.com"

# Create Message
$message = new-object system.net.mail.MailMessage $from, $to
$message.Subject = $subject
$message.Body = @"
Warning message from the Supertext Server
"@

# Set SMTP Server and create SMTP Client
$server = "209.162.190.6"
$client = new-object system.net.mail.smtpclient $server

# SO do it
"Sending an e-mail message to {0} by using SMTP host {1} port {2}." -f $to.ToString(), $client.Host, $client.Port
try {
$client.Send($message)
}
catch {
"Exception caught in CreateTestMessage: {0}" -f $Error.ToString()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest downloading and installing a command line emailing program. The best freeware one that I can see is:

http://www.beyondlogic.org/solutions/cmdlinemail/cmdlinemail.htm

From there, save the downloaded .exe to a good location on your HDD (possibly in c:/program files/bmail) and add that directory to your PATH ( see http://www.brightrev.com/how-to/windows/35-add-a-utilities-directory-to-your-pc.html?start=1 for instructions ).

From then, you could setup a small batch script such as this:

```
@echo off
bmail -s smtp.example.com -p 465 -t toemail@example.com -f fromemail@example.com -h -a "INSERT SUBJECT HERE" -b "INSERT MESSAGE TEXT HERE"
```

Then to send an email to that email address, just run the batch file.

If you want, you could change it to accept parameters so you can customise the message: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php .

Important: I'm pretty sure bmail won't work if the SMTP server requires authentication, so you'll need to find one you can use. Maybe set one up on the server without a username and password, and that can only be accessed from localhost?